# Real Analysis Folland Theorem 7.2

Tags: real-analysis

In the proof of Theorem 7.2 (Riesz Representation Theorem), Folland split it into 4 steps.
I am confused about part of the proof of step 3 which is proving $\mu$ satisfies equation (7.4) which is $\mu(K)=\inf\{I(f):f\in C_c(X),f\geq\chi_K\}$ for all compact $K\subset X$.

One of the direction to prove is $\mu(K)\leq\inf\{I(f):f\in C_c(X),f\geq\chi_K\}$.
The way Folland proves this is

> If $K$ is compact, $f\in C_c(X)$, and $f\geq\chi_K$, let $U_\epsilon=\{x:f(x)>1-\epsilon\}$.
> Then $U_\epsilon$ is open, and if $g\prec U_\epsilon$, we have $(1-\epsilon)^{-1}f-g\geq0$ and so $I(g)\leq(1-\epsilon)^{-1}I(f)$. Thus $\mu(K)\leq\mu(U_\epsilon)\leq(1-\epsilon)^{-1}I(f)$, and letting $\epsilon\to0$ we see that $\mu(K)\leq I(f)$.

I don't have a problem with the proof, but I am confused about why just saying $\forall f\in C_c(X)$ such that $f\geq\chi_K$, we have $\mu(K)=\int\chi_K\;d\mu\leq\int f\;d\mu=I(f)$ does not work.

In the previous step, $\mu$ is proven to be a Borel measure and we are working in LCH space which means compact set are closed, so the first equality makes sense.
Is this a shorter proof are am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: $\chi_{K}\notin C_{c}(X)$ so $\int\chi_{K}\,d\mu$ hasn’t been defined.

Comment: @mio I considered this but thought it was fine because in the previous step, it was proven the $\mu$ is a measure so the equality $\mu(K)=\int\chi_K\;d\mu$ is just by definition of integral. I'm not saying $I(\chi_K)=\int\chi_K\;d\mu$ which is an issue because the domain of $I$ is $C_c(X)$.

Comment: I have reread the text, the problem is we have not checked that $I(f)=\int f\,d\mu$. The only property of $I$ we know is it’s a positive linear functional.

Comment: @mio That makes so much sense. I did a few exercises before diving into the proof of the theorem and I guess I used the equality $I(f)=\int f\;d\mu$ too many times that I forgot it needs to be proven. Thank you.